# How to loop through "inserted" table in sybase trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, sap-ase

I am trying to loop through inserted table in Sybase trigger. Ultimately, i want to log all the inserted records information to an audit table.

I tried using temporary table in Sybase trigger. But, Sybase threw an error stating, it doesn't allow temporary tables inside trigger's.

I am not sure if i can use cursor. But, i believe cursors will be an overkill on performance.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: A cursor will be your best bet. You are Looping only through inserted records.....

Comment: Why would you want to loop through all 300 records?

Comment: @Meet - In my application, managers assign work (3000 records) to one user at a time. So, we have one insert statement to insert all records. We want to make sure, we record all allocations and also possible future re-allocations into audit table.

For example:
insert into Table_A (col_a, col_b, col_c)
select col_a, col_b, col_c from Table_B

Comment: wouldn't simple insert do it? Why would you loop through 3k records?

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain this using a cursor... Not to loop through the whole table but only what you have inserted. Here is a template that you can use inside your trigger. make sure to use table "inserted"..

**CURSOR TEMPLATE:**

```
declare cursor_inserted cursor for
select
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
from inserted
where
    column1 = some_value

--These variables should be same datatype as columns in your table
declare @id             int                 --for column1
declare @date1          datetime            --for column2
declare @string1        varchar(512)        --for column3

open cursor_inserted
fetch cursor_inserted into @id, @date1, @string1
    while (@@sqlstatus <> 2)
        begin
            print 'Here is where you can log everything you have inserted. Code goes here'
            fetch cursor_inserted into @id, @date1, @string1
        end 
close cursor_inserted
deallocate cursor_inserted
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't looping through 3000 inserted records using a cursor degrade the performance ?